# How to set the user define path for log/output/report file of robot framework on command line

Tags: selenium, pycharm, robotframework, automation-testing

I am using robot framework with pycharm.
I am running all the tests of my folder using

```
testfolder>robot .
```

I want to set the path of  log/output/report file to my customized location.
I have change the path of screenshot as D:/Screenshot folder in my variables.robot.
But How to set the path for mentioned file?
I also wanted to know
What is the common to run on terminal/cmd to run all the scripts of same folder with defined log file path?

Answer (score 0):

Robot Framework User Guide walks you through the [Basic Usage](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id173) in quite good detail. Additionally the same document contains a section for the [Different Command Line Options Available](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id963) where you can get quite good picture on the options you have available.

Specifically `--outputdir` or `-d` will make Robot to save Log.html, Report.html and output.xml to the specified folder.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Morkkis, the `-d` or `--outputdir` would do the trick. Also, it works for both command line and PyCharm Arguments field

For the screenshots, you could use the `screenshot_directory` command line argument. Please, check the Keyworkd documentation for more details  [ScreenShot Library Documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Screenshot.html)

Also, for the report/logs file location, you can use these variables:

- `${LOG LEVEL}`       Current log level.
- `${OUTPUT FILE}` An absolute path to the output file.
- `${LOG FILE}`        An absolute path to the log file or string NONE when no log file is created.
- `${REPORT FILE}` An absolute path to the report file or string NONE when no report is created.
- `${DEBUG FILE}`      An absolute path to the debug file or string NONE when no debug file is created.
- `${OUTPUT DIR}`      An absolute path to the output directory.